# Inconsistent behavior when slicing a 2d array in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, slice

Let's say I have a 2d array:

```
# SELECT ARRAY[ARRAY[1,2], ARRAY[3,4]];
     array     
---------------
 {{1,2},{3,4}}
(1 row)
```

Now, if I want to get the **first element** of each inner array, adding `(...)[:][1]` will do the trick:

```
# SELECT (ARRAY[ARRAY[1,2], ARRAY[3,4]])[:][1];
   array   
-----------
 {{1},{3}}
(1 row)
```

**BUT**: If I want to obtain the **second element** of each inner array, I have to opt for adding `(...)[:][2:2]`, as `(...)[:][2]` would return the untouched array again

```
# SELECT (ARRAY[ARRAY[1,2], ARRAY[3,4]])[:][2];
     array     
---------------
 {{1,2},{3,4}}
(1 row)

# SELECT (ARRAY[ARRAY[1,2], ARRAY[3,4]])[:][2:2];
   array   
-----------
 {{2},{4}}
(1 row)
```

What is the reason for this inconsistent behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING) explains this pretty well:

> If any dimension is written as a slice, i.e., contains a colon, then all dimensions are treated as slices. Any dimension that has only a single number (no colon) is treated as being from 1 to the number specified.

That is, when you are using slices, Postgres expects *all* dimensions to be slices.  Those that are not are defaulted to `1:n`.